# Change Height of a <td> without affecting the whole row height

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to manipulate the td inside a row of a table and not affecting the whole row ? 
what i want is to approximate the cells of the next row to the cell of this row . 
Please see the example ,it will help you to understand my needs.

i have tried multiple changing position exampleds but it doesnt work (dueing to my lack of experience in css )

nay help would be thankful

```css
.one-cell {
  width: 12%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.one-day {
  width: 12%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  /*padding-right:0.5%;*/
  border: white solid 1px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1%;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.row-tr {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 7%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 1%;
}
//only html writings  nothinf
```

```html
<table id="tbl_Grid" class="row-container">
  <thead>
    <tr class="row-days">
      <th class="one-day">Monday</th>
      <th class="one-day">tuesday</th>
      <th class="one-day">Wednsday</th>
      <th class="one-day">thursday</th>
      <th class="one-day">friday</th>
      <th class="one-day">saturday</th>
      <th class="one-day">Sunday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="bodyTable">

    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="row-tr">
      <td id="cell0" class="one-cell">0</td>
      <td id="cell1" class="one-cell">1</td>
      <td id="cell2" class="one-cell">2</td>
      <td id="cell3" class="one-cell">3</td>
      <td id="cell4" class="one-cell">4</td>
      <td id="cell5" class="one-cell">5</td>
      <td id="cell6" class="one-cell">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-tr">
      <td id="cell7" class="one-cell">7</td>
      <td id="cell8" class="one-cell">8</td>
      <td id="cell9" class="one-cell">9</td>
      <td id="cell10" class="one-cell">10</td>
      <td id="cell11" class="one-cell">11</td>
      <td id="cell12" class="one-cell">12</td>
      <td id="cell13" class="one-cell">13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-tr">
      <td id="cell14" class="one-cell">14</td>
      <td id="cell15" class="one-cell">15</td>
      <td id="cell16" class="one-cell" rowspan="2" style="height: 100px;">16</td>
      <td id="cell17" class="one-cell" rowspan="2" style="height: 100px;">17</td>
      <td id="cell18" class="one-cell" rowspan="2" style="height: 100px;">18</td>
      <td id="cell19" class="one-cell">19</td>
      <td id="cell20" class="one-cell">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-tr">
      <td id="cell21" class="one-cell">21 i want to go up </td>
      <td id="cell22" class="one-cell">22 i want to go up</td>
      <td id="cell23" class="one-cell">23</td>
      <td id="cell24" class="one-cell">24</td>
      <td id="cell25" class="one-cell">25</td>
      <td id="cell26" class="one-cell">26 i want to go up</td>
      <td id="cell27" class="one-cell">27 i want to go up</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-tr">
      <td id="cell28" class="one-cell">28</td>
      <td id="cell29" class="one-cell" rowspan="4" style="height: 200px;">29</td>
      <td id="cell30" class="one-cell">30</td>
      <td id="cell31" class="one-cell">31</td>
      <td id="cell32" class="one-cell" rowspan="4" style="height: 200px;">32</td>
      <td id="cell33" class="one-cell" rowspan="4" style="height: 200px;">33</td>
      <td id="cell34" class="one-cell" rowspan="4" style="height: 200px;">34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-tr">
      <td id="cell35" class="one-cell">35 i want to go up</td>
      <td id="cell36" class="one-cell">36</td>
      <td id="cell37" class="one-cell">37 i want to go up</td>
      <td id="cell38" class="one-cell">38 i want to go up</td>
      <td id="cell39" class="one-cell">39</td>
      <td id="cell40" class="one-cell">40</td>
      <td id="cell41" class="one-cell">41</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-tr">
      <td id="cell42" class="one-cell">42</td>
      <td id="cell43" class="one-cell">43</td>
      <td id="cell44" class="one-cell" rowspan="6" style="height: 300px;">44</td>
      <td id="cell45" class="one-cell">45</td>
      <td id="cell46" class="one-cell">46</td>
      <td id="cell47" class="one-cell">47</td>
      <td id="cell48" class="one-cell">48</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-tr">
      <td id="cell49" class="one-cell">49 i want to go up</td>
      <td id="cell50" class="one-cell">50 i want to go up</td>
```

Comment: it is not possible to do it with a table, but you can simulate it using a dive inside each td and giving it the desired height...

Comment: *what i want is to approximate the cells of the next row to the cell of this row*. I don't think I understand this sentence. Is the example what you want or is it what you are getting and you want something else? You might want to build your table using `div`s instead of `table`.

Comment: Think you probably want to do this with `<div>` and use something like isotope.js or masonry.js to align everything

Comment: @lurker 10  this what i am getting  , i want the the  cell number (21,22,26,27) to become nearer to (14,15,19,20)

Comment: @markdibe tables don't work that way

Comment: @charlietfl  hmm i have tried the div thing but i got another problem , (dealing with positions of the text inside each div ,  if you share me your email i can send it to you .

Comment: i sont want to share it here because they will downvote it directly

Comment: Don't ask for emails. Create a **runnable** demo in a sandbox like jsfiddle, plunker ,  codepen, etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174439/discussion-between-mark-dibe-and-charlietfl).

Comment: @charlietfl https://jsfiddle.net/sLte03c6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you use rowspan on a column, it takes space of columns below.

While other columns that are parallel leaves a placeholder which needs to be filled with another table row with only number of columns which are not spanned.

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td rowspan="2">16</td>
      <td rowspan="2">17</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>41</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>48</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>54</td>
      <td>55</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: would you please explain to me more ,

Comment: See

tr | | |
tr . | .
tr - this tr must have only two td's to fill out the dots.
tr | | |